# Where to get '--fldMean' and '--fldSD' for single-end Salmon run

Tags: rna-seq, salmon

I need to run `single-end` `bulk-RNAseq` `salmon` - based alignment and I am not sure what I should supply as `--fldMean` and `--fldSD` which seem to be crucial for the `single-end` experiment alignment. Can they be somehow derived from the `FASTQ` files that I have, or should I be provided with them by someone who did the experiment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the salmon documentation [here](http://salmon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/salmon.html#using-salmon), it is correct that both of these are essential for single end experiments:

> Since the empirical fragment length distribution cannot be estimated from the mappings of single-end reads

From the discussion [here](https://github.com/COMBINE-lab/salmon/issues/127) it would appear that you can't estimate these parameters at all via the FASTQ files alone.

The fragment length refers to the physical molecule of D/RNA captured in the [library prep](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4351865/) stage which you have sequenced (in part) on your sequencer.  Thus ideally this sort of data should come from a [bioanalyzer](https://web.uri.edu/gsc/agilent-2100-bioanalyzer/) trace from whoever performed the library prep or similar QC step, this should ideally show the mean fragment length and standard deviation.